# Relations between same model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, model

Which is the best way to implement "recursive" relations in ruby on rails?

eg.

- Manager has many Employees
- Employee has many Interns
- Manager has many Interns;

Manager, Employee and Intern may have multiple "Client" (has many)

but all that models have lots in common: attributres, methods, views.

But if I use a single model "User" with a role attribute and a N:N table for relations I'll lost all the Rails "helper" and methods.

I will be not able to do "manager.employees.clients"

- Which is the best way to implement it?
- Is there a gem or a clever way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called self join. have you searched rails documents? Check this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins